# Piping Get-Childitem into SelectString selects file contents instead of file names

Tags: powershell, pipeline

I am trying to do the equivalent of the linux command `find . | grep [search_string]` in Powershell.

When I call `Get-ChildItem -recurse | Select-String [search_string]`, it matches the *contents* of files, instead of just the file names that I'm trying to match.

How do I get it to only look at the file names?

Answer (score 2):

Expand the `Name` or `FullName` property of the file objects first:

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse |
    Select-Object -Expand FullName |
    Select-String [search_string]
```

To get the full name of the matches expand the `Line` property of the resulting `MatchInfo` objects:

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse |
    Select-Object -Expand FullName |
    Select-String [search_string] |
    Select-Object -Expand Line
```

or use a `Where-Object` filter instead of `Select-Object`:

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse |
    Select-Object -Expand FullName |
    Where-Object { $_ -match [search_string] }
```

Comment: How can I get it to give me the full path of the files that select?

Answer (score 0):

A better use for this would be to use the `Where-Object` cmdlet, and just match the file names that way.

For instance, let's say you had a directory like this, and you wanted to just get the files with ham in the name.

```
Directory: T:\stack


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
d-----         4/5/2016  11:28 AM                cat-1
d-----         4/5/2016  11:28 AM                cat-2
d-----         4/5/2016  11:28 AM                cat-3
d-----         4/5/2016  11:28 AM                cat-4
d-----         4/5/2016  11:28 AM                cat-5
d-----         4/5/2016  11:28 AM                dog-1
d-----         4/5/2016  11:28 AM                dog-2
d-----         4/5/2016  11:28 AM                dog-3
```

Using this syntax `Dir | Where-Object Name -like *string*` you can easily find the matching files or folders:

```
dir | ? Name -like ham*


    Directory: T:\stack


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
d-----         4/5/2016  11:28 AM                ham-1
d-----         4/5/2016  11:28 AM                ham-2
d-----         4/5/2016  11:28 AM                ham-3
d-----         4/5/2016  11:28 AM                ham-4
d-----         4/5/2016  11:28 AM                ham-5
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy

```
function locate{
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$False,Position=2)]
        [string] $loc = '.',
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$True,Position=1)]
        [string] $search
    )
    (gci $loc -Recurse).FullName | Select-String $search
}
```

## Usage

```
PS C:\Users\username\Documents> locate somefile

C:\Users\username\Documents\somefile.csv
```

or

```
PS C:\Users\username\Documents> locate somefile ..

C:\Users\username\Documents\somefile.csv
C:\Users\username\Downloads\somefile.txt
C:\Users\username\Pictures\somefile.pst
```